# 32 bit office component in 64 bit environment

Tags: c#, office-interop

we are upgrading some 32 bit C# windows applications to 64 bit. There are some office interop components (like `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`) used in it currently. Will it cause any issues if we use the same components in the 64 bit environment also?

Comment: From my own experience (nothing official), YES. You'll likely need to install the 64bit version of Office for that to work

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to mix 32 and 64.  I have several utilities that I have written to support a legacy Access97 database based application.  Everything has to be 32 bit in the equation or it just won't work.  You can't mix the two.